# XML parsing and storing the parsed tag values in csv or excel in python

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing, elementtree

Hi I'm learning Python programming and I'm trying to parse 100's of XML files, extract only the required tags and their values and store them to readable format like csv or excel.
I'm using ElementTree but it parses the sub child nodes as well. And using DataFrame to store the parsed data in csv but only the last value is being stored.Can someone pls help with the parsing and storing values?

There are 3 things to fix im trying to fix in the code:

1. send links of 100's of XML files as input for parsing , or access a csv file that has 100's of XML file link stored and use them as input (instead of using local XML file one by one as in the code below)
2. Do not parse the sub /child node which has the same tag name (i.e parse 'label','status' of only the  tag and not its tag as in the XML file below)
3. Store or send the parsed values from all the xml files to one (or more)csv or excel files in a table format where tag name is column and its values are rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

tree=et.parse(r'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

Label = []
Status = []
StartTime = []

count=0
if count==0:
 for lbl in root.iter('label'):
  print(lbl.text)
  Label.append(lbl.text)
  count=count+1
  
count1=0  
if count1==0:
 for sts in root.iter('status'):
  print(sts.text)
  Status.append(sts.text)
  count1=count1+1

count2=0  
if count2==0:
 for st in root.iter('startTime'):
  print(st.text)
  StartTime.append(st.text)
  count2=count2+1

Jobs_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Label,Status,StartTime,EndTime,Audio)),
                      columns=['Label','Status','StartTime','EndTime','Audio'])
Jobs_df.to_csv("pyXML.csv")
```

My XML file:

```
<session>
 <meta>
 <xmlURL>https://s3.amazonaws.com/test.xml</xmlURL>
 </meta>
 <server/>
 <result>
  <audio>
   <startTime>0</startTime>
    <endTime>5880</endTime>
   </audio>
   <words>
     <word>
       <label>a</label>
        <status>BAD</status>
        <score>0.0</score>
        <startTime>990</startTime>
        <children/>
         <phonemes>
           <phoneme>
            <label>AH</label>
            <status>BAD</status>
            <evaluation>SUBSTITUTION</evaluation>
            </phoneme>
          </phonemes>
      </word>
    </words>
 </result>
</session>
.
.
.
and so on..
```

Require output in csv or excel format:

| label | status | startTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Bad | 990 |

Can someone please help with this assignment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from os import stat
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import urllib.request as rq

csv_delimiter = ','

def parse_xml(data):
    tree = et.fromstring(data)
    root = tree.getroot()
    label = root.find('./result/words/word/label').text
    status = root.find('./result/words/word/status').text
    startTime = root.find('./result/words/word/startTime').text

    with open('data.csv', '+a') as f:
        f.write(label + csv_delimiter + status + csv_delimiter + startTime + '\n')



def grab_xml_url(csv_file_with_xml_file_links):
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Label' + csv_delimiter + 'Status' + csv_delimiter + 'StartTime\n')

    with open(csv_file_with_xml_file_links, 'r') as f:
        try:
            for link in f:
                fl = rq.urlopen(link)
                data = fl.read().decode('utf-8')
                parse_xml(data)
        except:
            pass


grab_xml_url('path/of/the/xml/links/file.csv')
```

grab_xml_url is a function that reads csv file with xml file links line by line, grabs their content from internet and passes their content to the parse_xml function. That's why you have to create csv file with links

--

##For single xml file

```py
from os import stat
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import urllib.request as rq

csv_delimiter = ','

def parse_xml(filePath):
    tree = et.parse(filePath)
    root = tree.getroot()
    label = root.find('./result/words/word/label').text
    status = root.find('./result/words/word/status').text
    startTime = root.find('./result/words/word/startTime').text

    with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Label' + csv_delimiter + 'Status' + csv_delimiter + 'StartTime\n')
        f.write(label + csv_delimiter + status + csv_delimiter + startTime + '\n')
    
parse_xml('./tree.xml')
```

Comment: Thank you! This did create a csv file with column names 'Label' etc , but there were no XML parsed values under it

Comment: My codes above are intended for multiple xml files as you wrote. Let me to change my codes to parse only single xml file in your case.

Comment: Thank You so much! I'm tring for multiple XML files and it has started working but it parses only the first occurence of <word> tag in the XML files. I have multiple <word> tags under /result/words .Is there any soln for this.

Comment: Could you put here one sample xml file with multiple word tag?

Comment: [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/17CXI7gK7pOSRjwRAVBjNGqNobE3M8qld/view?usp=sharing  
Here is the XML file

Comment: Sorry about that but xml file is empty. Also google drive warns me about your file because xml file actually is executable file. Could you fix that problem and upload it again?

Answer (score 0):

- new in [pandas 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html) `read_xml()`
- this can be used to simplify your solution

```
xml = """<session>
 <meta>
 <xmlURL>https://s3.amazonaws.com/test.xml</xmlURL>
 </meta>
 <server/>
 <result>
  <audio>
   <startTime>0</startTime>
    <endTime>5880</endTime>
   </audio>
   <words>
     <word>
       <label>a</label>
        <status>BAD</status>
        <score>0.0</score>
        <startTime>990</startTime>
        <children/>
         <phonemes>
           <phoneme>
            <label>AH</label>
            <status>BAD</status>
            <evaluation>SUBSTITUTION</evaluation>
            </phoneme>
          </phonemes>
      </word>
    </words>
 </result>
</session>"""

import pandas as pd
import io
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.read_xml(io.StringIO(xml), xpath="/session/result/words/word")

df.loc[:,["label","status","startTime"]].to_csv(Path.cwd().joinpath("SO.csv"))
```